# Libgdx Animation run loop only twice

Tags: loops, animation, libgdx

So I'm trying to stop an animation after running twice. 
I am playing the animation by setting

```
Animation blink = new Animation(BLINK_TIME, frames); // parameters are my fields
```

This is how i get my current frame:

```
   if(animate){
      stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); //stateTime was initialized to 0
      currentFrame.setRegion(blink.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true)); 
}
else 
   currentFrame.setRegion(defaultRegion);  // again, my own field!
```

Everything works fine uptill here when the `animate` field is true.
Now I want to stop the animation, this is what I do for it:

```
if(blink.isAnimationFinished(stateTime)){
        blinkTimes++;
        if(blinkTimes>=2)
            animate = false;
    }
```

The problem is, `isAnimationFinished(stateTime)` never gets called. I guess it has to do something with looping animation. Can someone please point me in the right direction? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the Problem!

`isAnimationFinished(stateTime)` does not work when animation is being played in the loop. So, I had to play it in `Animation.Normal` mode and use `false` in `blink.getKeyFrame(stateTime, false)` telling the Animation class to run it in non-loop mode!

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems ok. I think you have initialized

```
stateTime = 0;
```

inside the render method or update method where firstly its value = 0 and then you add deltaTime to it.. In the end it never reaches to position where animation gets finished.
I think you should log the value of stateTime when your

```
if(animate) // log what is your stateTime
```

And 1 more thing

```
  if(blink.isAnimationFinished(stateTime)){
    blinkTimes++;
     stateTime = 0 ; //----------- because your animation should start from begining else it will complete 2 cycles in no time.
    if(blinkTimes>=2)
        animate = false;
}
```

I hope this helps.. and if i am not getting your question properly just let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have rechecked, my stateTime is only in the constructor of my class and there is only the above code in my render method. 
I logged my stateTime, here it is: 
State Time: : 0.017742615
State Time: : 0.03272076
State Time: : 0.04981166
State Time: : 0.066713706
State Time: : 0.08279193
State Time: : 0.105113775
State Time: : 0.11688316
State Time: : 0.13282415
State Time: : 0.15010346
State Time: : 0.16728222
State Time: : 0.18312132
State Time: : 0.20014429
Also i logged it inside blink.isAnimationFinished code block and found that control never reaches there!